# Fasm loop using eax not working

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, fasm

I am trying to make a for loop in assembly where the `EAX` register is set to 5, and increased until it is greater than 10. Each time it increases, it outputs it's current value. When I execute my program, it goes in an infinite loop which only outputs 4. Why is `EAX`'s value 4? Why is register `EAX` not increasing as it should?

```
include 'include/macro/import32.inc'
format PE console
entry start

section '.text' code readable executable

start:

mov eax,5
loop1:
    inc eax
    push eax
    push msg2
    call [printf]
    cmp eax,10
    jb loop1

call [getchar]
push 0
call [exit]

section '.data' data readable writable
msg2  db "%i",0dh,0ah,0

section 'idata' import data readable
library msvcrt,"msvcrt.dll"
import msvcrt,printf,"printf",getchar,"getchar",exit,"exit"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output from `printf` is returned in `eax` which contains the number of characters printed: 3 in your case (the digit, CR, and LF). Since that is less than 10, you loop up, add 1 (which makes it 4), print that, and repeat.

What you need to do is store eax (`push eax`) before setting up the `printf` call, then restore it (`pop eax`) after `printf` returns like:

```
loop1:
    inc  eax
    push eax        ; store eax
    push eax
    push msg2
    call [printf]
    add  esp,8      ; clean the stack from the printf call 
    pop  eax        ; restore eax
    cmp  eax,10
    jb   loop1
```

Or use a different register such as `ebx` for your loop variable.

Comment: You also are not cleaning the print parameters, so they build up on the stack and your pop won't pop the right thing.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I totally spaced that one. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I have used a secondary register to hold the value as you suggested and it worked like a charm. Your example also works fantastic.

Comment: @Johnathan: the problem may still be the register you are using. Typically, `ecx` and `edx` are not preserved, so if you are using eitehr of these, your counter may still be getting trashed.

Answer (score 1):

Always preserve EAX before using printf. printf destroys your EAX

```
inc eax
push eax
...call to printf
pop eax
cmp eax,10
```